# I tried to run a c++ application I made in eclipse (its .exe) and it says "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing and Try to reinstall

Tags: c++

I use MinGW with eclipse. I am new to c++.

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
```

If anyone has had this problem or knows the solution, please respond.

Answer (score 0):

You have below options:

1. By adding `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to your compiler flags.
2. You can add this directory to your PATH environment variable

Comment: ?Do I do that in eclipse or cmd

Comment: how are you building? Its possible in both.

Comment: @user3164113 I am not versatile with eclipse... you can try that cmd line and check here how to add in eclipse http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm

Answer (score 0):

Search for that library in the MinGW directory and then copy it to the same path of the executable.

The other way is to compile the program statically.

Comment: how do i acces my compiler flags?

Comment: I dont know how to set it on Eclipse, I have used it only a couple of times. Sorry bro.